# Как правильно это пишется?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

> Или в зеркале с вопросом кто ты?

Answer (score 0):

*Или в зеркале с вопросом: "Кто ты?".*

(Точку в конце ненавижу, но — предложение повествовательное.)

Можно ещё так:

*Или в зеркале с вопросом — кто ты?*

*Или в зеркале — с вопросом "кто ты?"*.

Трудно без контекста.

Comment: Подождите, так кавычки после двоеточия не нужны, поскольку прямая речь неотличима от косвенной.

Comment: И даже если поставить кавычки, то не нужна точкс, поскольку прямая речь, вопросительный знак поглощает точку.

Comment: Прямая речь с вопросом ВНУТРИ повествовательного предложения, - это про точку. Про кавычки: прямая речь после двоеточия. Про лайки, - и где он? Я вона скока вариантов накидала - и все как один грамотные.